# Dynamics 2011 SystemForm Timestamps

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm querying an on-premises installation of Dynamics CRM 2011 via SQL Server Management Studio.

I'd like to find CreatedOn, CreatedBy, ModifiedOn, ModifiedBy for a Form(by Form I mean like how each entity has the "Information" form). I've tried doing this with the SystemForm view, but the closest column I can find is PublishedOn, and I don't see a PublishedBy.

The solution doesn't have to be in SQL. I just need to find the info.

Answer (score 0):

The information is not available (practically you can't know who made a customization and when)